# Mimic UITextView's default double tap behavior

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Does anyone know what methods are called when the user taps with two fingers in a `UITextView`?

When the user taps with two fingers, the whole text in a paragraph is selected. I'd like to implement the same selection programmatically to make this paragraph selection available in my custom single tap gesture method.

Comment: Have you already set up a custom single tap gesture and associated method?

Comment: Yes, `- (IBAction)tapTextViewGesture:(id)sender {
    
    NSLog(@"TAP");

   }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the `UITextView` double tap gesture recognizer's default behavior, I think `selectAll:` is the method being invoked to handle the text selection. You can similarly force your text view to select the text upon recognition of your single tap gesture recognizer by utilizing `selectAll:` in your existing `tapTextViewGesture:` method (as described in your comment).

If you want the text options to show automatically as they do in response to the default double tap gesture recognizer (i.e. cut, copy, paste, etc.), set `selectAll:` to `self`:

```
- (IBAction)tapTextViewGesture:(id)sender {
    [self.textView selectAll:self]; 
}
```

Otherwise, to simply select the text without showing the menu, set it to `nil`:

```
- (IBAction)tapTextViewGesture:(id)sender {
    [self.textView selectAll:nil]; 
}
```

**Updated**

As pointed out by the OP in the comments, the `UITextView` double tap gesture recognizer initially only results in the selection of a single paragraph.

First, display the edit menu from the current cursor position:

```
// Access the application's shared menu
UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

// Calculate the cursor's position within the superview
// and convert it to a CGRect
CGPoint cursorPosition = [self.textView caretRectForPosition:self.textView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
CGPoint cursorPositionInView = [self.textView convertPoint:cursorPosition toView:self.view];
CGRect menuRect = CGRectMake(cursorPositionInView.x, cursorPositionInView.y, 0, 0);

// Show the menu from the cursor's position
[menu setTargetRect:menuRect inView:self.view];
[menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

Then to select the current paragraph, here's what I recommend:

```
// Break the text into components separated by the newline character
NSArray *paragraphs = [self.textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

// Keep a tally of the paragraph character count
int characterCount = 0;

// Go through each paragraph
for (NSString *paragraph in paragraphs) {

    // If the total number of characters up to the end
    // of the current paragraph is greater than or
    // equal to the start of the textView's selected
    // range, select the most recent paragraph and break
    // from the loop
    if (characterCount + paragraph.length >= self.textView.selectedRange.location) {
        [self.textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(characterCount, paragraph.length)];
        break;
    }

    // Increment the character count by adding the current
    // paragraph length + 1 to account for the newline character
    characterCount += paragraph.length + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this methods works, but not for selecting separate paragraphs, it selects all the text in UITextView. The text in my textView consists of several paragraphs. These paragraphs divided by \n\n space. In my app I need to select only the paragraph on which the user taps, not the whole text in TextView. Don't you know how to implement paragraph selection?

Comment: Need the same functionality like in Notes App but on single tap, here is the screenshot [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xch41jowszsnea1/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-28%20at%2015.16.24.png?dl=0) . You can see on this screenshot that it only selects paragraph, not the whole text when the user taps this paragraph.

Comment: Thank you Lyndsey. Your code works, but In my case (shared menu) not always appeared at the top of the paragraph. So I came out with the mix of your code [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27673217/3287785) and the code  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27673272/3287785) by @WorldOfWarcraft .

Comment: @Adelmaer Oh, I think I know what you mean...since the top of the paragraph may be out of view and thus the menu will show up above the text view... I guess it's probably best to either (1) show the menu *before* selecting the text so it shows up where the user clicked or (2) to scroll to the beginning of the paragraph... For now, I'll edit my answer to option 1.

Answer (score 1):

See the [`UITextInputTokenizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTokenizer_Protocol/index.html) protocol reference:

> ***An instance of a class that adopts the UITextInputTokenizer protocol is a tokenizer; a tokenizer allows the text input system to evaluate text units of different granularities. Granularities of text units are always evaluated with reference to a storage or reference direction.***

By the protocol, use `- (UITextRange *)rangeEnclosingPosition:(UITextPosition *)position withGranularity:(UITextGranularity)granularity inDirection:(UITextDirection)direction` and set the UITextGranularity to `UITextGranularityParagraph` to detect the textRange with granularity you had set up.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

  if (touches.count == 2) {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.textView];

    //calculate the distance from touch
    UITextPosition *position = [self.textView closestPositionToPoint:touchLocation];
    NSUInteger distanceFromTouch = [self.textView offsetFromPosition:self.textView.beginningOfDocument
                                                          toPosition:position];
    //calculate the position by offset 
    UITextPosition *positionOffset = [self.textView positionFromPosition:self.textView.beginningOfDocument
                                                  offset:distanceFromTouch];

    //set up the granularity
    UITextGranularity granularity = UITextGranularityParagraph;

    //implement the protocol
    id<UITextInputTokenizer> tokenizer = self.textView.tokenizer;
    UITextRange *textRange = [tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:positionOffset
                                               withGranularity:granularity
                                                   inDirection:UITextWritingDirectionLeftToRight];

    //select the textRange
    [self.textView setSelectedTextRange:textRange];

    self.textView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad;

  }
}
```

Don't forget to assign the protocol. `@interface ViewController ()<UITextInputTokenizer>`

Comment: Thanks, this is also works fine for the whole text in UITextView but not for paragraphs, I also added  [self.textView becomeFirstResponder]; to make it work in my - (IBAction)tapTextViewGesture:(id)sender method. But in my case I need to select only the paragraph touched(tapped) by the user, not the whole text in my textView. If you double tap in notes app on a paragraph, only the paragraph is selected, not the whole text. I need the same functionality. Here is the example: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xch41jowszsnea1/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-28%20at%2015.16.24.png?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you, this UITextInputTokenizer is really great. But not showing copy on tap in my App. That's why I finally came out with the mix of your code with <UITextInputTokenizer> and granularity and the code from Lyndsey's answer for showing up Copy menu.

Comment: @Adelmaer You mean the cut/copy/paste menu, why my device is showing?

Comment: I think it was my fault, because I've put your code in - (IBAction)tapTextViewGesture:(id)sender method, not in - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event method. Finally decided to make a custom edit menu and everything works fine. Thanks once again, your answer helped a lot and also solves the problem.